# Remove metadata of pdf generated by LaTeX

Tags: metadata

Not sure how relevant my question is to this forum but I will go ahead and ask anyway :). I use LaTeX to create pdf which, as expected, indicates "TeX" as the source. I need to upload this pdf online but want to avoid uploading original LaTeX files. I removed the metadata of the pdf using AdobePro, "PDF Optimizer" option. But somehow the site still detects the pdf as TeX generated file. Does anyone know how to make the pdf completely clean?

Comment: Can I ask why? I can think of several legitimate reasons to want to do this and in some cases there are alternatives which might be worth considering but they tend to be case-specific so I've no idea if they apply in this case or not.

Comment: I use pdftk to strip all metadata. Check this [blog post](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/stripping-metadata-from-pdf-files/) for details.

Answer (score 13):

You can do all these with `hyperref` package. Add these lines to your preamble and change the contents as in `pdfproducer={},`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
%    pdfstartview={FitW},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={Certificate},    % title
    pdfauthor={Dr. Harish Kumar},     % author
    pdfsubject={TEQIP certificates},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Dr. Harish Kumar},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={},  % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={Certificates,} {TEQIP} {Participation}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
%    pdfstartview={FitW},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={Certificate},    % title
    pdfauthor={Dr. Harish Kumar},     % author
    pdfsubject={TEQIP certificates},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Dr. Harish Kumar},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={},  % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={Certificates,} {TEQIP} {Participation}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I have deliberately left all other (probably irrelevant) items in `hypersetup`. For details, see the `hyperref` manual.

Comment: Thanks but if click on the "Additional Metadata" tab, you will still see source as "MiKTeX"

Comment: Additional Metadata >> Advanced >> http://ns.adobe.com/pdfx/1.3/. This is one location where I found MikTeX info. There might be others

Comment: @JohnSmith My experiments show that it can be deleted with adobe pro. This is the easiest workaround as you are using adobe pro anyway :-)

Answer (score -4):

MetaClean is a powerful tool to view, remove and edit metadata of Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Visio), OpenOffice (word processors, spreadsheets and presentations) and PDF (versions 1.0 and higher) documents. Clean hundreds documents at once.

http://adarsus.com/en/metaclean.html

Microsoft Windows, Linux, Unix and Mac OS X Platforms

Comment: As it stands, this reads a bit too much like an advert for comfort: the question is specifically about PDFs, and indeed Office docs are off-topic for us. Could you perhaps make it more focussed on the issue at hand?

Comment: Just tried it. Yes, it removes metadata. However, it also adds new metadata, namely the name of itself as `CreatorTool` and `Creator`.