# Ensure anonymity when using latexmk -view=pdf

Tags: pdf, latexmk, metadata

I am doing a review for an article where I need to write some equations myself **and** want/have to stay anonymous.
So far I plan to just LaTeX my notes, compile them with `latexmk -view=pdf` and send them in.
My fear is that `latexmk`/`pdflatex` adds metadata that will break the anonymity of the review process.
I checked the result with `pdfinfo`, and could not find info that would identify me in this case. But in general I would like to not only rely on some defaults of `pdflatex,` but to know if there is a cheap way (preferably via CLI options) to guarantee, that there is no identifying metadata.

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608593/removing-metadata-from-a-pdf ?

Comment: Did you have a look at this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151241/remove-metadata-of-pdf-generated-by-latex